# Gulp Rename illegal operation

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-rename

My gulp file looks like:

```
function aureliaJsonPath(name) {
    return `./aurelia_project/aurelia.${name}.json`;
}

gulp.task('use-login-au-json', () => {
    return gulp.src(aureliaJsonPath('login'))
        .pipe(rename('aurelia.json'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./aurelia_project'));
});
```

> [11:59:18] Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open '... base directory...\aurelia_project\aurelia.json'

Basically, I have a directory with `aurelia.login.json` which I want to copy and rename to `aurelia.json` in the same directory.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem here was because in previous tests I had accidentally created a directory called `aurelia.json` inside the directory I was trying to create the file `aurelia.json`

After deleting that directory it then worked perfectly.